# show that there is not positive integer n satisfying $4n<n^2<5n$

Tags: inequality

I do not know where to begin, I know that if I choose some n, to be say n=3, this does not hold, and it doesn't hold for any n > 0. But that's not a formal mathematical proof.

Comment: divide by $n$, then you will see

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there exists a  $n_0 > 0 $ integer such that

$$ 4n_0 < n_0^2 < 5n_0 $$

Dividing by $n_0$ (which we can do since $n_0 \neq 0$), we obtain

$$ 4 < n_0 < 5 \; \; \text{Contradiction}$$

Comment: Don't write this way. It appears as if you are saying that there is an $n_0$ such that some equivalence holds, which is not what you mean.

Comment: Que tal ahora Andres ?

Comment: Better! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take away a $n$, i.e

$ 4n < n^2 < 5n \implies 4 < n < 5$

Can $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (integers)?